# Style not taken in account on GridViewColumn ToolTip

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

So I have the following problem :

In my `ListView`, I want to add `ToolTips` to specific `GridViewColumns`.
Sometimes these `ToolTips` are empty, and I need to hide them.

When I have a `ToolTip` on a `ListView` Line, I encounter no problem doing the following in my `App.xaml` file:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But in the case a `ToolTip` is applied to only one column of my `ListView`, my XAML is the following :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Name}" Width="100">
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Tag="{Binding Name}" 
                       MouseMove="mouseOverNameRepere">
               <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                   <StackPanel>
                      <Grid>
                         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                    Text="{Binding Path=ToolTipModifications}" 
                                    TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                      </Grid>
                   </StackPanel>
               </TextBlock.ToolTip>
            </TextBlock>
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

How can I hide the `ToolTip` when it is empty? The code in my `App.xaml` is not working.
Also tried to do it in code behind :

```
TextBlock item = (TextBlock)sender;
ToolTip toolTip = (ToolTip)item.ToolTip;
```

But second line gives me an exception as `item.ToolTip` is a `StackPanel` object and cannot be converted?
In fact I calculate the `ToolTip` content only when I enter the `TextBox` element, so I thought I would then check and apply `toolTip.Visibility` at this moment, but I couldn't.

Comment: I guess you don't need the `StackPanel` and the `Grid` in your tool tip, do you?

Comment: you can set the tooltip to `null`, then it won't show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAML for WPF: Hide ToolTip Popup when blank Tooltip text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340160/xaml-for-wpf-hide-tooltip-popup-when-blank-tooltip-text)

Comment: Your `Style` should work if you set the `ToolTip` property of the `TextBlock` like this: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Tag="{Binding Name}" MouseMove="mouseOverNameRepere" ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTipModifications}" />`

Comment: @dymanoid in fact in that example I don't need StackPanel and Grid, just need to put a TextBlock, the StackPanel and Grid are here just because I took the code from another ToolTip. I had two answers so I will try them now

Comment: @mm8 thanks, your solution worked perfectly. As I am curious on how all of that works, I also will try the other options. If you can/want, put an answer so I will select it as good answer. Thanks all for your replies.

Comment: @icebat also thanks for answer, had a quick view on it, the problem is it asks to use converters, and until today didn't manage to use converters, but as said in my previous comment will try it also and will tell you if it works(if I manage to use it)

Comment: @icebat thanks for the link I could look at it, but would like to understand something : what is the advantage to use the converter, rather than Style? I think using style once in app.xaml is much better for this kind of situation? Anyway will try it tomorrow, it maybe will help me to understand better how to use converters, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Style` should work if you set the `ToolTip` property of the `TextBlock` like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Tag="{Binding Name}" MouseMove="mouseOverNameRepere" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTipModifications}" />
```

Comment: perfect thanks, I also took a look at the 2 other answers, and confirm your answer is from far the simpliest. Thanks (just will look at the proposal of icebat that is interesting solution, but more complicated than yours).

Answer (score 1):

Use Rectangle instead of Tooltip

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Name}" Width="100">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Tag="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTipModifications}" MouseEnter="UIElement_OnMouseEnter"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Then check if ToolTipModifications is empty in MouseEnter event

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rectangle.ToolTip.ToString()))
        {
            rectangle.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution is also working good thanks, bad I can select only good answer, and (on my point of view) mm8 is better as it is much easier, and I can apply my Style automatically. Thanks anyway for your time

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockDefaultStyle}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Name}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="6000"> 
        </Style> 
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle> 
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: You should not only provide some code snippet, but also explain why it is a good solution,

Comment: @Rakesh Dhamejani in fact your answer looks very similar to mm8 comment higher, but much more longer code, and I don't understand all of the code.